# Check if array contains 'equal' object

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a simplified example, but say I want to generate 5 unique positions on a 100x100 grid. These positions will be stored in an array [[x, y], ...].

The tried the obvious method of generating a random x and y and checking to see if the array [x, y] is already in the result array. If it is, generate different values, if not add it to the result array.

```js
result = [];
while (result.length !== 5) {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    if (!result.includes([x, y])) {
        result.push(array);
    }
}
```

However, this will never find the duplicates, as the arrays are technically different objects. So, what is the preferred method for detecting if an array contains an 'equal' array/object?

Comment: Are you opposed to using a lodash function for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29951293/using-lodash-to-compare-arrays-items-existence-without-order it may make this much easier than writing a comparison loop

Comment: `[x,y] !== [x,y]` even though values are identical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `some()` instead of `includes()` and use `join()` before compare

```
while (result.length !== 5) {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    if (!result.some(i => i.join() === [x, y].join())) {
        result.push(array);
    }
}
```

You can't compare two arrays by simple equality in js. For example `[]===[]` is `false`. Because both arrays have difference references

```js
console.log([] === []); //false
```

Same is the case with `includes()`

```js
let pts = [[1,2],[5,6]];

console.log(pts.includes([1,2])); //false

console.log(pts.some(x => [1,2].join() === x.join())); //true
```

Comment: This works here since all the values are single digits, but it might be better to use a separator for the join, which would allow it to distinguish between pairs like `[11, 2]` and `[1, 12]` if the matrix could be bigger.

Comment: Should have stated in the post, I need this to work with multiple digit numbers. Will edit the post.

Comment: You can just ignore the separator parameter like this: `.join()`. This will add a `,` by default

Comment: @adiga Thanks for information. I actually forgot about that.

Comment: `.toString()` works as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in conjunction with `destructuring`:

**Example:**

```js
let arr = [[1,2],[3,4]];

console.log(arr.some(([x, y]) => x === 3 && y === 4));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

So, your example, can be reworked to this:

```js
let result = [];

while (result.length !== 5)
{
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    if (!result.some(([a, b]) => a === x && b === y))
    {
        result.push([x, y]);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(`${[x,y]} is already on the array!`);
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```